# Why do I need to cast these returned results?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, casting

```
    // Insert new record
    ArtworkingDataContext dc = new ArtworkingDataContext();
    tblArtworkData NewRecord = new tblArtworkData()
    {
        dateCreated = DateTime.Now,
        templateID = TemplatesID,
        userID = UsersID
    };
    dc.tblArtworkDatas.InsertOnSubmit(NewRecord);

    // Set new values
    this.Loaded = true;
    this.ID = NewRecord.ID;
    this.DateCreated = (DateTime)NewRecord.dateCreated;
    this.TemplateID = (int)NewRecord.templateID;
    this.UserID = (int)NewRecord.userID;
}
```

When I set the new values, ID doesn't need casting, but the others do, otherwise I get:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'int?' to 'int'.
```

I'm getting bored already of casting all my returned data, what am I doing wrong?  And why doesn't the ID need a cast?

Comment: Are those fields defined as nullable in your model or mapping?

Comment: @Mike, they are in my database as a field allowing nulls yes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apart from all the other answers here - this could indicate a bigger issue in the DB design an Linq to Sql Mapping.

Your object clearly expects these values to be provided all the time; but the database columns must be nullable.  If the data going in the table will never be null, then you should make them NOT NULL and then set the 'Nullable' property in the designer for each of the properties to 'false'

Then you'll no longer need either a cast nor a `.HasValue` check.

Equally, instead of these you can do:

```
Value = nullable ?? default_Value;
```

Where `default_Value` is some kind of sentinel integer - e.g. `-1` or `0`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to cast `int?` to `int`, but rather, just use `.Value` on the object (or, rather, the `GetValueOrDefault()` extension method if that is safer for you).  The error is just complaining that you are passing a nullable type to a property that is not nullable.

Comment: Of course, only use `GetValueOrDefault` if that's what makes sense. It might make more sense to throw (that's what .Value does); or to change this.TemplateID and this.UserID to be nullable as well; or to change the NewRecord.TemplateID to be not-nullable.

Comment: Thanks, do you mind explaining what exactly you mean be passing a nullable type to a non nullable property?  Do I need to change my database field to not allow nulls?

Comment: @Tom: well, that's for you to decide. Does it make sense for those fields to ever be null? If so, leave the DB as is and change your code. If those fields don't make sense as null, then change the DB (and your mapping).

Comment: @Mart, thanks, yeah I don't need any null values for any of these fields.

Answer (score 2):

It seems `NewRecord.templateID` and `NewRecord.userID` are of type `Nullable<int>` or `int?` in C#.

A wrapper class that enables an `Int32`, in this case, to be null.

The ID field is probably set as 'not null' in the database.  Look at your DB schema, templateID and userID possibly allow nulls, which get translated to `Nullable<T>` types.

[Nullable Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

> what am I doing wrong?

If the values in the data record are of type `int?`, and the object that you're populating has properties of type `int`, then the first thing you're doing wrong is casting.  And not because writing `(int)` all the time is boring.  This:

```
this.UserID = (int)NewRecord.userID;
```

is going to throw a `InvalidOperationException` when `NewRecord.userID` contains `null`.  There, now what was boring has become exciting in a way you didn't want.

There are two possible responses to this:

1. "But that will never happen."  In that case, fix whatever is creating `NewRecord` so that its properties aren't nullable.  You'll probably find that yes, actually it can happen, because the underlying column in the database is nullable.
2. "OK, since the database column is nullable, I guess it can happen."  In this case, you need to find out *why* the column is nullable.  If the user ID contains NULL, what does this mean, and what should your application be doing when it is?  You will probably find that you need to make your local object's properties `int?` instead of `int`, and then include logic that handles the case where their value is null.

A lot of people have suggested that you use the null coalescing operator or some other way of assigning a default value.  Sometimes that's a good idea - if you know what the null value is supposed to mean.  But the idea of using `??` to assign a sentinel value isn't really solving the problem, it's changing what is already a perfectly serviceable sentinel value - `null` - into a value that only works if it can't naturally occur in the value space.  Sometimes you have to do this - if, for instance, you're talking to some piece of code that doesn't support null values - but it's something you should do very reluctantly.

Answer (score 1):

you have to check if the nullable values do have a value.

```
int x;
int? nullable;

if(nullable.HasValue)
   x = nullable;
```

the reason is that int != int?

int? is just a short form for

> `Nullable<int>`

Answer (score 1):

I guess that these fields are Nullable in the database.

Since the data could be null then the C# maps these to Nullable data fields - e.g. `int?` (which is shorthand for `Nullable<int>`)

Instead of casting them, you should probably check for null using `.HasValue` and then use the `.Value` property - or you could use the null coalescence operator - `??`

If you want to avoid this conversion, then the only way I can think of is to change your database so that these fields can't be null (and also possibly to provide a default value for them)

---

Your ID field isn't Nullable in the database - so it's represented by and `int` and not a `int?` in your C#

Hope that helps

Stuart

Answer (score 1):

You need something like `this.DateCreated = NewRecord.dateCreated.GetValueOrDefault();`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is related to Linq.  The compiler is telling you that there is no implicit cast between a `Nullable<T>` and `T`.  Obviously, for normal values, the cast is easy.  But it doesn't know what to do if `dateCreated` is `null`

Answer (score 1):

TemplateID and UserID are not int they're `System.Nullable<int>` and that is why you have to cast them.  Either make this.TemplateId and This.UserID `Nullable<int>` 
or use the .Value property on Nullable objects.